# Get the last line separator

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I think this is a pretty common task and there should be some fast and concise solution. I have a quadword and I want to get the lowest byte position which is equal to 0x0A (line break in Linux). I wrote the following simple program:

```
SYS_exit equ 0x3C

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 0x0A
    mov rbx, [dt]
    mov rcx, 0x07
    loop:
        mov r13, rbx
        and r13, 0xFF
        cmp r13, 0x0A
        jz ok
        shr rbx, 8
        dec rcx
        jnz loop
        jmp fail
    ok:
        mov rax, SYS_exit
        mov rdi, 8
        sub rdi, rcx
        syscall
    fail:
        mov rax, SYS_exit
        mov rdi, -1
        syscall


section .data
    dt: dq 0xAB97450A8733AA1F
```

And it works pretty much fine. `strace ./bin` prints

```
execve("./bin", ["./bin"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
exit(5)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 5 +++
```

But the program looks ugly and actually I'm looking for a way to make this  as fast as possible. Can you give some optimization advice?

Comment: Since you have working code, your question is more properly asked on [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please ask to migrate the question to [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: highest byte position = the last one? Because in your example you jump to `ok` on first one. So which one?

Comment: @Ped7g Sure, the typo. I meant the first one of course, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the program looks ugly

Congratulations for noticing :P

> I'm looking for a way to make this as fast as possible

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so you should use it.  You can do this in a couple instructions, using pcmpeqb / pmovmskb to get a bitmap of byte-compare results, then use a bit-scan instruction like [`bsr`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html) (scan reverse gives you the index of the highest set bit).

```
default  rel      ; don't forget this: RIP-relative addressing is best for loading/storing global data

_start:
    movq    xmm0, [dt]             ; movq xmm0, rdx  or whatever works too.
    pcmpeqb xmm0, [newline_mask]   ; -1 for match, 0 for no-match
    pmovmskb edi, xmm0
    bsr     edi, edi                  ; index of highest set bit

    mov  eax, SYS_exit
    jz  .not_found                 ; BSR sets ZF if the *input* was zero
    ; [dt+rdi] == 0xA
    syscall                        ; exit(0..7)

.not_found:
    mov  edi, -1                   ; exit only cares about the low byte of its arg; a 64-bit -1 is pointless.
    syscall

section .rodata
    align 16
    newline_mask: times 16 db 0x0a

section .data
    dt: dq 0xAB97450A8733AA1F
```

Obviously in a loop you'd keep `newline_mask` in a register (and then you can broadcast-load it with AVX `vbroadcastss`, or SSE3 `movddup`, instead of needing a whole 16 byte constant in memory).

And of course you can do this for 16 bytes at a time with a `movdqu` load, or 32 bytes at a time with AVX2.  **If you have a large buffer, you're basically implementing a backwards `memcmp` and should look at optimized library implementations.**  They might combine `pcmpeqb` results for a whole cache line with `por`, so they save 3/4 of the `pmovmskb` work until the end when they sort out which part of the cache line had the hit.

If you care about AMD CPUs (where `bsr` is slow), maybe separately test for input=0 with `test edi,edi` / `jz` before using `tzcnt`.  (`tzcnt(x)` gives you `31-bsr(x)`, or 32 if the input was all-zero.)  If you can depend on BMI2 being available...

---

If you wanted to do it with a scalar loop, you could use byte compares on the low byte of a register instead of copying and masking the value.

```
    ; we test byte 7 first, so start the counter there.
    mov  edi, 7         ; no idea why you were using a 64-bit counter register
   ; loop body runs with edi=7..0
.loop:                ; do{
    rol  rbx, 8         ; high byte becomes low

    cmp  bl, 0xa        ; check the low byte
    je   .found

    dec  edi
    jge  .loop        ; } while(--edi>=0) signed compare
   ; not found falls through with edi=-1

 .found:
    mov  eax, SYS_exit
    syscall           ; exit(7..0) for found, or exit(-1) for not-found
```

Depending on what you're doing with the result, you might arrange your loop counter differently.

Comment: BTW, this gets the *last* line separator, like your question title asks for.  I assumed it was a bug in your code.  Use `bsf` if you want the first.  (Or in the scalar loop, use `shr rbx,8` *after* checking the low byte).

Comment: @fuz: you can use it, but I'm not sure it would be a *good* use even though it has the BSF functionality built-in.  On Skylake it's 3 uops for p0, with 12c latency.  But `pcmpeqb` is 1c for p01, `pmovmskb` is 2 to 3c for p0, and `bsf` is 1c for p1.  So this has better throughput and latency than `pcmpistri`.  `pcmpistri` could possibly be useful if you don't know the length and have to check for a terminating byte as well, i.e. to implement `strchr` instead of `memchr`.  But probably still no; probably only useful for more complicated searches like character ranges.

Comment: And if you have AVX2, SSE4.2 string instructions aren't worth considering for this; 32 bytes at a time blows them away.