# Fastest Way to determine the position of a SIMD compared register

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, avx

I have an already SIMD compared `__m128i` register, which results in like something:

```
0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0 // in shorts
0, -1, 0, 0 // in ints
```

What is the fastest/cheapest way to get the position of the int where the bits are set? There is only one int inside of the `__m128i` set to 1.

Example:

```
-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  ->  0
0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0  ->  1
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0  ->  2
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1  ->  3
```

One additional note, I have only AVX and lower available, so no AVX2 or AVX-512. I'm using C++ and Intel instrincs.

---

Edit: This is my current code:

```
__m128i comparableLow = _mm_set_epi32(key - 1, key - 1, key - 1, key - 1);
__m128i comparableHigh = _mm_set_epi32(key + 1, key + 1, key + 1, key + 1);

__m128i mData = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(arr));
__m128i l1 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(mData, comparableLow);
__m128i u1 = _mm_cmplt_epi32(mData, comparableHigh);
__m128i r1 = _mm_and_si128(u1, l1);
```

Comment: `vmovmskps` / `bsf` (or `tzcnt`).  See [Get the last line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50496029).  If this is the result of a `vpcmpeqd` or `vcmpps`, you have dword elements so you can use `movmskps` to get a bitmap of the high bit.  Or if you always have pairs of `int16_t`?  IDK why you're showing it as `int16_t` elements if they always come in 32-bit chunks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496029/get-the-last-line-separator)  (except that was for byte elements so maybe not).

Comment: Sorry one thing to add, i'm using c++ not assembler.

Comment: Then use intrinsics for those instructions, to get your compiler to emit them, of course.  `unsigned bitmap = _mm_movemask_ps( _mm_castsi128_ps(v));`  / `int pos = _bit_scan_forward(bitmap);`.  (Or whatever BSF intrinsic your compiler likes best:  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=411,3941,3941,433,1508,408,5534,392&techs=AVX,AVX2,Other&text=bsf)

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(mData, _mm_set1_epi32(key))`?  That's equivalent to your `(x > (key-1)) & (x < (key+1))` unless I'm missing something.  And just to clarify, you want the result as an `int`, rather than as the low element of a `__m128i`, right?  But movmskps / bsf is probably still the fastest way, even if it takes a `movd` to get back to an `__m128i`.

Comment: I'm using the comparison for tree traversal, so in the internal nodes i will not find the key itself, i have to determine in which range the key is to follow the correct pointer(or offset).

Comment: Then either your example is over-simplified from your real code (with `+1` / `-1` instead of your actual range), or you have a bug, because as written I think it's exactly equivalent to checking for exact equality only.  But ok, you'll want the offset as an `int` or `unsigned int`, so that's good, `movmskps` / `bsf` is exactly what you want.

Comment: BTW, you might want to align your b-tree elements or whatever they are, if that doesn't waste a lot of space, so your loads never cross a cache-line boundary.  On Intel hardware, cache-line split loads add at least 5 cycles of load-use latency to pointer chasing in the critical path of your tree-traversal.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to determine the cach-line size and how to avoid the crossing?

Comment: Assume the cache-line size is 64B.  That's the case on all CPUs with AVX, and is unlikely to change in the future.  But you only need your data to be 16-byte aligned so your vector load will be naturally aligned and will never cross any boundaries wider than that.

Comment: And BTW, this may not actually be a duplicate of anything!  I couldn't find any other SO posts with `[x86] code:_mm_movemask_ps _BitScanForward`.  movemask -> bitscan is a pretty well-known idiom, at least I thought it was.  You'll find it it most libc `memchr`/`strchr`.  Often people only want to know if any or all elements met a condition, rather than *which one*, or to use the `movemask` result as an integer index, but I'm really surprised I didn't find an existing answer with that code.  But an asm and C versions of it got posted in 1 day!  I may type up an answer if I get around to it.