# What is the purpose of the MoveMask for SSE and AVX

Tags: .net-core, f#, x86, sse, avx

### Questions

1. What is the purpose or intention of a MoveMask?
2. What's the best place to learn how to use x86/x86-64 assembly/SSE/AVX?
3. Could I have written my code more efficiently?

### Reason for Questions

I have an function written in F# for .NET that uses SSE2. I've written the same thing using AVX2 but the underlying question is the same. What is the intended purpose of a `MoveMask`? I know that it works for my purposes, I want to know why.

I am iterating through two 64-bit float arrays, `a` and `b`, testing that all of their values match. I am using the `CompareEqual` method (which I believe is wrapping a call to `__m128d _mm_cmpeq_pd`) to compare several values at a time. I then compare that result with a `Vector128` of `0.0` 64-bit float. My reasoning is that the result of `CompareEqual` will give a `0.0` value in the cases where the values don't match. Up to this point, it makes sense.

I then use the `Sse2.MoveMask` method on the result of the comparison with the zero vector. I've previously worked on using `SSE` and `AVX` for matching and I saw examples of people using `MoveMask` for the purpose for testing for non-zero values. I believe this method is using the `int _mm_movemask_epi8` Intel intrinsic. I have included the F# code and the assembly that is JITed.

Is this really the intention of a `MoveMask` or is it just a happy coincidence it works for these purposes. I know my code works, I want to know WHY it works.

#### F# Code

```ml
#nowarn "9" "51" "20" // Don't want warnings about pointers

open System
open FSharp.NativeInterop
open System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86
open System.Runtime.Intrinsics
open System.Collections.Generic

let sseFloatEquals (a: array<float>) (b: array<float>) =
    if a.Length = b.Length then
        let mutable result = true
        let mutable idx = 0
        
        if a.Length > 3 then
            let lastBlockIdx = a.Length - (a.Length % Vector128<float>.Count)
            let aSpan = a.AsSpan ()
            let bSpan = b.AsSpan ()
            let aPointer = && (aSpan.GetPinnableReference ())
            let bPointer = && (bSpan.GetPinnableReference ())
            let zeroVector = Vector128.Create 0.0

            while idx < lastBlockIdx && result do
                let aVector = Sse2.LoadVector128 (NativePtr.add aPointer idx)
                let bVector = Sse2.LoadVector128 (NativePtr.add bPointer idx)
                let comparison = Sse2.CompareEqual (aVector, bVector)
                let zeroTest = Sse2.CompareEqual (comparison, zeroVector)

                // The line I want to understand
                let matches = Sse2.MoveMask (zeroTest.AsByte ())
                if matches <> 0 then
                    result <- false

                idx <- idx + Vector128.Count

        while idx < a.Length && idx < b.Length && result do
            if a.[idx] <> b.[idx] then
                result <- false

            idx <- idx + 1

        result

    else
        false
```

#### Emitted Assembly

```
; Core CLR 5.0.921.35908 on amd64

_.sseFloatEquals$cont@11(System.Double[], System.Double[], Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit)
    L0000: push rdi
    L0001: push rsi
    L0002: push rbp
    L0003: push rbx
    L0004: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0008: vzeroupper
    L000b: mov eax, 1
    L0010: xor r8d, r8d
    L0013: mov r9d, [rcx+8]
    L0017: cmp r9d, 3
    L001b: jle short L008e
    L001d: mov r10d, r9d
    L0020: and r10d, 1
    L0024: mov r11d, r9d
    L0027: sub r11d, r10d
    L002a: lea r10, [rcx+0x10]
    L002e: mov esi, r9d
    L0031: test rdx, rdx
    L0034: jne short L003c
    L0036: xor edi, edi
    L0038: xor ebx, ebx
    L003a: jmp short L0043
    L003c: lea rdi, [rdx+0x10]
    L0040: mov ebx, [rdx+8]
    L0043: xor ebp, ebp
    L0045: test esi, esi
    L0047: je short L004c
    L0049: mov rbp, r10
    L004c: xor r10d, r10d
    L004f: test ebx, ebx
    L0051: je short L0056
    L0053: mov r10, rdi
    L0056: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    L005a: cmp r8d, r11d
    L005d: jge short L008e
    L005f: mov esi, eax
    L0061: test esi, esi
    L0063: je short L008e
    L0065: movsxd rsi, r8d
    L0068: vmovupd xmm1, [rbp+rsi*8]
    L006e: vmovupd xmm2, [r10+rsi*8]
    L0074: vcmpeqpd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2
    L0079: vcmpeqpd xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    L007e: vpmovmskb esi, xmm1
    L0082: test esi, esi
    L0084: je short L0088
    L0086: xor eax, eax
    L0088: add r8d, 4
    L008c: jmp short L005a
    L008e: cmp r9d, r8d
    L0091: jle short L00c8
    L0093: cmp [rdx+8], r8d
    L0097: jle short L00c8
    L0099: mov r10d, eax
    L009c: test r10d, r10d
    L009f: je short L00c8
    L00a1: cmp r8d, r9d
    L00a4: jae short L00d1
    L00a6: movsxd r10, r8d
    L00a9: vmovsd xmm0, [rcx+r10*8+0x10]
    L00b0: cmp r8d, [rdx+8]
    L00b4: jae short L00d1
    L00b6: vucomisd xmm0, [rdx+r10*8+0x10]
    L00bd: jp short L00c1
    L00bf: je short L00c3
    L00c1: xor eax, eax
    L00c3: inc r8d
    L00c6: jmp short L008e
    L00c8: add rsp, 0x28
    L00cc: pop rbx
    L00cd: pop rbp
    L00ce: pop rsi
    L00cf: pop rdi
    L00d0: ret
    L00d1: call 0x00007ffcef38a370
    L00d6: int3

_.sseFloatEquals(System.Double[], System.Double[])
    L0000: mov r8d, [rcx+8]
    L0004: cmp r8d, [rdx+8]
    L0008: jne short L0012
    L000a: xor r8d, r8d
    L000d: jmp 0x00007ffc99000480
    L0012: xor eax, eax
    L0014: ret
```

Comment: For question #2: I think you should try x86 emulators online. https://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/Asm86/ I don't work on these emulators myself. Use discretion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MoveMask` just extracts the high bit of each element into an integer bitmap.  You have 3 element-size options: [`movmskpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movmskpd) (64-bit), [`movmskps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movmskps) (32-bit), and [`pmovmskb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb) (8-bit).

This works well with SIMD compares, which produce an output that has all-zero when the predicate is false, all-one bits in elements where the predicate is true.  All-ones is a bit-pattern for `-QNaN` if interpreted as an IEEE-FP floating-point value, but normally you *don't* do that.  Instead movemask, or AND, (or AND / ANDN / OR or `_mm_blend_pd`) or things like that with a compare result.

---

`movemask(v) != 0`, `movemask(v) == 0x3`, or `movemask(v) == 0` is how you check conditions like at least one element in a compare matched, or all matched, or none matched, respectively, where `v` is the result of `_mm_cmpeq_pd` or whatever.  (Or just to extract signs directly without a compare).

For other element sizes, `0xf` or `0xffff` to match all four or all 16 bits.  Or for AVX 256-bit vectors, twice as many bits, up to filling a whole 32-bit integer with `vpmovmskb eax, ymm0`.

---

What you're doing is really weird, using a 0.0 / NaN compare result as the input to another compare with `vcmpeqpd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2` / `vcmpeqpd xmm1, xmm1, xmm0`.  For the 2nd comparison, that can only be true for elements that are `== 0.0` (i.e. +-0.0), because `x == NaN` is false for every `x`.

If the second vector is a constant zero (`let zeroTest = Sse2.CompareEqual (comparison, zeroVector)`, that's pointless, you're just inverting the compare result which you could have done by checking a different integer condition or against a different constant, not doing runtime comparisons.  (`0.0 == 0.0` is true, producing an all-ones output, `0.0 == -NaN` is false, producing an all-zero output.)

---

To learn more about intrinsics and SIMD, see for example [Agner Fog's optimization guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/); his asm guide has a chapter on SIMD.  Also, his VectorClass library for C++ has some useful wrappers, and for learning purposes seeing how those wrapper functions implement some basic things could be useful.

To learn what things actually *do*, see [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html).  You can search by asm instruction or C++ intrinsic name.

I think MS has docs for their C# System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86, and I assume F# uses the same intrinsics, but I don't use either language myself.

---

Related re: comparisons:

- [Check that at least 1 element is true in each of multiple vectors of compare results - horizontal OR then AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091855/check-that-at-least-1-element-is-true-in-each-of-multiple-vectors-of-compare-res)
- [Get the last line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496029/get-the-last-line-separator) - pcmpeqb -> pmovmskb -> `bsr` to find the position of the last match element in a vector of compare results.  Bit-scan reverse on the compare mask.  Often you want to scan forward to find the first match (or invert and find first mismatch, like for `memcmp`).  e.g. [Compare 16 byte strings with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999284/compare-16-byte-strings-with-sse)
  Or popcount them if you're counting occurrences by matching against a loop-invariant vector of a  broadcasted character: [How can I count the occurrence of a byte in array using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552656/how-can-i-count-the-occurrence-of-a-byte-in-array-using-simd) - instead of movemask, use the compare result as integer 0 / -1.  SIMD subtract from a vector accumulator in the inner loop, then horizontal sum of integer elements in an outer loop.
- [SIMD instructions for floating point equality comparison (with NaN == NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951714/simd-instructions-for-floating-point-equality-comparison-with-nan-nan) - useful exercise in understanding how NaNs work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Peter pointed out already.

Yes, `MoveMask` (`movmskp`) works well with comparisons, if you need indices as general-purpose integer bask, to do like `bsf` or `popcnt` or whatever.

As you are determining just the fact of nonzero, `Sse41.TestZ` (or `Avx.TestZ` for AVX) which compiles to `ptest` could be better, as it makes the result to a flag directly, without populating a general purpose register.

Comment: Yup, `ptest same,same` / `jnz` is 3 uops, same as `pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1` / `pmmovmskb eax,xmm0` / `cmp eax,0xffff + je` (macro-fused cmp+branch), but the PTEST version doesn't need a `_mm_setzero_si128()` vector constant in a register, and doesn't destroy the value (which could cost a movdqa without AVX).  It's also smaller machine-code size.  Plus if you're using scalar `setcc` or `cmov` which can't macro-fuse with `test` or `cmp` the way a branch can, the PTEST version is fewer uops.

Comment: But if you have a compare result already (rather than testing if a vector is all-0 / non-zero), using `ptest` (`Sse41.TestZ`) is worse if you're branching in the result.  Only 2 more uops after the pcmp with movemask vs. 3 with ptest.  (Intel and AMD can both fuse `cmp/jcc` into a single uop for the relevant cases.)

Comment: Missed the point that there is macro fusion, and there has to be FP comparison. Indeed the compiler/jit did not emit `cmov` where it could: `L0082: test esi, esi L0084: je short L0088`